# Change YouTube resolution from the dev console

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming

I got really annoyed that YouTube always sets my resolution to auto when I start a video, I just want it to be in 480p. So I'm trying to make a tampermonkey script that'll automatically change the resolution to 480p.

So far I've tried copying the resolution change request from the dev console and reading the YouTube api docs, but haven't found anything that works. So is there a way to change the playback resolution from the dev console?